# how to create a working generic linked list with Anytype?

Tags: java, generics, singly-linked-list

Hello I am have created a generic class called GenLinkedList(which is singly-linked linkedList) but I am fairly new to understanding generic so my program is not implementing correctly.

my node class look like:

```
public class Node<AnyType> {
    public AnyType value;
    public Node<AnyType> next;
    
    public Node(AnyType value, Node<AnyType> next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
    
    public Node(AnyType value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

My GenLinkedList class look like:

```
public class GenLinkedList<AnyType> {
    private Node<AnyType> head;
    private Node<AnyType> tail;
    int size = 0;
    
    public void addFront(AnyType value) {
        if(head == null) {
            head = new Node(value);
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            head = new Node(value,head);
        }
        size++;
    }
}
```

My main looks like:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         GenLinkedList list = new GenLinkedList();      // try <int> didnt work! What am I do wrong?
         
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
             list.addFront(i);
         }
         
         System.out.println(list);
         
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a primitive type, you need the wrapper type `Integer`. Like,

```
GenLinkedList<Integer> list = new GenLinkedList<>();
```